# How to sum the values from dynamically created input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created Dynamic Add / Remove fields. Everything is working perfectly. I want sum of values from **Amount** field to be displayed on real time basis using JavaScript. I have tried but am unable to do. I am not much familiar with JavaScript.

**Following is code:**

```js
var i = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  //fadeout selected item and remove
  $(document).on('click', '#remove-allocation-fields', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function() {
      $(this).parent().empty();
      return false;

    });

  });

  var rows = '<div class="all-allocation-fields"><div class="row"><div class="col-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="allocate_items[]"></div></div><div class="col-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control code" id="code" name="allocate_amount[]"></div></div><div class="col-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove-allocation-fields">Remove</button></div></div></div>';

  //add input
  $('#add-allocation-fields').click(function() {

    $(rows).fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#fund-allocation-fields');
    i++;
    return false;

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header text-center">
    <b>Allocation of Funds</b>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-5"><label><b>Allocation Items</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label></div>

      <div class="col-5"><label><b>Amount</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label></div>

      <div class="col-2"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-5">

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="allocate_items[]">
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-5">

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control code" id="code" name="allocate_amount[]">
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-2">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-allocation-fields">Add</button>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="fund-allocation-fields">

    </div>

    <small class="form-text text-muted"><i>Total amount must be equal to the goal amount.</i></small>
    <div id="sum"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use add `keyup` event listener and calculate sum as:

```
function calculateSum() {     //Add a calculateSum function
  var sum = 0;
  $("input[name='allocate_amount[]']").each(function() {
    sum += +this.value || 0;
  });
  $("#sum").text(sum);
}


//fadeout selected item and remove
$(document).on('click', '#remove-allocation-fields', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function() {
    $(this).parent().empty();
    calculateSum();          //Call calculateSum to update the sum valaue
    return false;
  });
});


$("body").on("keyup", "input[name='allocate_amount[]']", calculateSum); //update when keyup
```

Demo:

```js
var i = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;

    $("input[name='allocate_amount[]']").each(function() {
      sum += +this.value || 0;
    });
    $("#sum").text(sum);
  }


  //fadeout selected item and remove
  $(document).on('click', '#remove-allocation-fields', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function() {
      $(this).parent().empty();
      calculateSum();
      return false;
    });
  });

  var rows = '<div class="all-allocation-fields"><div class="row"><div class="col-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="allocate_items[]"></div></div><div class="col-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control code" id="code" name="allocate_amount[]"></div></div><div class="col-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove-allocation-fields">Remove</button></div></div></div>';

  //add input
  $('#add-allocation-fields').click(function() {

    $(rows).fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#fund-allocation-fields');
    i++;
    return false;

  });


  $("body").on("keyup", "input[name='allocate_amount[]']", calculateSum);



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header text-center">
    <b>Allocation of Funds</b>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-5"><label><b>Allocation Items</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label></div>

      <div class="col-5"><label><b>Amount</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label></div>

      <div class="col-2"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-5">

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="allocate_items[]">
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-5">

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control code" id="code" name="allocate_amount[]">
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-2">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-allocation-fields">Add</button>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="fund-allocation-fields">

    </div>

    <small class="form-text text-muted"><i>Total amount must be equal to the goal amount.</i></small>
    <div id="sum"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code... It is working fine. But there is a problem. When we remove the input field the total sum doesn't get updated. It shows the older value only.

Comment: You can put the content of keyup to a function. Call that function on both keyup and remove the field. Sorry cant create a sample coz im on the road now.

Comment: Sry to trouble u but since I m not much familiar with JavaScript, I m not able to update the code... Can u plz update it as per ur convinience... Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with this code:

```
function calcAmount(){
   var amount = 0;
   $('input[name="allocate_amount[]"]').each(function(){
        amount = amount +  $(this).val();
    });
    return amount;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("input[name="allocate_amount[]]").blur(function(){
        $("#sum").html(calcAmount());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I try to update your code: and it works fine:

main changes:
- assign ids to input fields
- make changes in function

have a look to jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/dupinderdhiman/ygvphmxq/31/

Main changes:

```
  var sum = eval($('#value1').val()) + eval($('#value2').val());
          $('#sum').text(sum);
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header text-center">
        <b>Allocation of Funds</b>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-5"><label><b>Allocation Items</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label></div>

        <div class="col-5"><label><b>Amount</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label></div>

        <div class="col-2"></div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-5">

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id='value1' name="allocate_items[]">
      </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-5">

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control code" id='value2' name="allocate_amount[]">
      </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-2">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-allocation-fields">Add</button>

        </div>

      </div>

        <div id="fund-allocation-fields">

        </div>

            <small class="form-text text-muted"><i>Total amount must be equal to the goal amount. <span id="sum"></span></i></small>


      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var i = 0;

      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        //fadeout selected item and remove
        $(document).on('click', '#remove-allocation-fields', function(event) {

          event.preventDefault();
          $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function() {
            $(this).parent().empty();
            return false;

          });

        });

        var rows = '<div class="all-allocation-fields"><div class="row"><div class="col-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="allocate_items[]"></div></div><div class="col-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control code" id="code" name="allocate_amount[]"></div></div><div class="col-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove-allocation-fields">Remove</button></div></div></div>';

        //add input
        $('#add-allocation-fields').click(function() {
    debugger;
          $(rows).fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#fund-allocation-fields');
          i++;
          var sum = eval($('#value1').val()) + eval($('#value2').val());
          $('#sum').text(sum);
          return false;

        });

      });

    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Actually I want total of only Amount input field... Your code is correct but it is making total of Allocation Items & Amount... I want only total of Amount...